# sqlplus one foreign key to multiple tables? is ti possible

Tags: sqlplus

i wrote an SQL query like this:

```
FOREIGN KEY(CAR#)REFERENCES VEHICLE(SERIAL#),
FOREIGN KEY(SALE#)REFERENCES BUYER(SALE#),
FOREIGN KEY(SALE#)REFERENCES SELLER(SALE#),
```

am i allowed to do this considering i have all the tables required?

Comment: i can make a table with it, but I do not know how to tell if it works... i am new to this and trying to learn.

Comment: I think if there is no error it probably works. try inserting invalid values to see what happens.